# Adding custom callback to user model with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to add this callback to my User model, which I generated using Devise.

```
  before_save :check_invite_code

  def check_invite_code
    if self.invite_code == 'first20'
      User.save
    else
      {icon: 'error', message: "Sorry that's not a valid invite code"}
    end
  end
```

The issue I am having is with passing the returned hash with the else block back to my view. Typically I'd be able to use the icon and message in the flash in my controller. I'm not sure how to do that. I don't have a `UsersController` because devise takes care of a the routing with the path being `devise/controller#action`. So do I create a devise directory inside of controllers, then create the corresponding controllers like sessions, etc and override the devise methods? Looking for some guidance from someone with devise experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to customize the UserController you can easily do that by

```
rails generate devise:controllers [scope]
```

For example

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)